# XSLT: Run XSLT transformation within a XSLT file for specific set of nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Just Curious,

I have two XSLT files, One is the main XSL file used for transformation, and the second has templates for a specific nodeset.

Is it possible to run the transformation within another XSL file and get the results for a specific node-set? eg: call the second XSLT in a template function of the first XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

A stylesheet module can [import or include](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#combining-modules) the templates (and variables, functions, keys, etc) defined in another stylesheet, with an `xsl:import` or an `xsl:include` statement.

There's also the [`transform()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-transform) XPath function which you can use to execute another XSLT transformation, which allows you to specify the secondary stylesheet module dynamically, i.e. at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged the question xslt-30, and XSLT 3.0 greatly expands the range of possibilities for how to invoke a transformation.

However, stylesheet modules (files) are not themselves units of execution. By the time you've compiled a multi-module stylesheet, there's no way of distinguishing which module a particular template rule came from. The best way to do this would be to follow the discipline of using one mode for each module (and XSLT 3.0 encourages this with a `default-mode` attribute on `xsl:stylesheet`). You can then invoke a transformation by naming the initial mode that you want to apply.